# Make a div have a top-most position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, actionscript-3

I'm not quite sure how to ask this question. What I'm trying to do is have an element on the bottom of my page that will always stick to the bottom, but if the page is too short it will be pushed down by the other elements on the page.

Example:

The left side middle graphic and the right titles are all contained within #mainBodyContent. If the browser window is small enough that this div runs into the "Latest in Geek" flash box, I want the flash box to be pushed down. However if #mainBodyContent isn't running into the flash box, I want the flash box to stick to the bottom in the place where it's at currently. I'm rather confused as how to pull it off.

Any suggestions/help out there? Am I making sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning combined with padding. Example can be seen here:

[Static Footer Example](http://jsfiddle.net/98aYH/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body { height:100%; }

    /* layout */
    #container { 
        width:800px; margin: 0px auto; 
        position: relative; min-height: 100%; 
    }
    #top { height: 12px; } /* margin on header breaks liquid layout */
    #header { position: relative; }
    #content { padding-bottom: 72px; } /* 60px footer height plus 12px padding */
    #footer {
        clear: both;
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        width:100%;
        height:60px;   
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background-color: red;
     }
    .section { 
        margin-top: 12px; 
        padding-top: 12px; 
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="top"></div>    
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div><!-- end header div -->

        <div id="content">

            <div class="section">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>

        </div><!-- end content div -->

        <div id="footer">Footer content here</div>

    </div><!-- end container div -->
</body>
```

Comment: your example is definitely what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to get it to work in my own custom way. Does using a z-index break it?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the CSS selector `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

A quick stab gives you most of what you're looking for. The concern (for me) is that while the resulting footer is at the bottom of the page, the elements above will run underneath it. Some scripting could change that (and is likely how it's done in your example), but this is a start.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            background-color: Red;
            height: 200px;
        } 

        *html #footer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            background-color: Red;
            height: 200px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>A test</div>
        <div id="footer">Here's my footer</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the height of your content to the height of your window.  If the window is larger than the height of your content, then set the footer to `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`.

css:

```
#footer
{
    bottom: 0; /* this line does nothing until you set position: fixed; */
}
```

javascript:

```
function setFooterPosition()
{
    var foot = document.getElementById("footer");
    var docEl = document.documentElement;
    foot.style.position = docEl.clientHeight < docEl.scrollHeight ? "" : "fixed";
}
window.onload = setFooterPosition;
window.onresize = setFooterPosition;
```